# Dynamic Type instantiation C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, instantiation, activator, objectinstantiation

I'm looking to instantiate an object at runtime having its type in a string but also it's value in a string. eg:

```
string myType = "System.Int32";
string myValue = "3";
```

I'm looking to create an instance of myType and cast/assign myValue into the instance i just created.

I've looked into Activator.CreateInstance :

```
object objectInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(myType));
```

But i can't get to pass my value to my instance (could be anything : int16/32/64, double, bool, custom type...).

Thank you for your help

Comment: How do you know which property to set in case of custom types?

Comment: Anyway, look into type converters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the type object and then use the `Convert` class:

```
string myType = "System.Int32";
Type type=Type.GetType(myType)

string myValue = "3";
object convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(myValue, type);
```

Answer (score 1):

That only works on value types...

```
var t = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
object x = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

if (t.IsValueType)
   x = Convert.ChangeType("2", t);
```

Comment: Thank you ! Works perfectly fine :)
Is there any way to specify a custom type is a Value type ?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean @Caracole.